# Helping others is a good habit. Which part of speech is "Helping" & "others" here?

Tags: parts-of-speech

Helping others is a good habit.

Which part of speech is "Helping" & "others" here? I think helping here is noun & others is pronuoun.

Comment: Good question. OP could have shown some background effort, though.

Comment: @GregLee _Helping_ is definitely no verb. It's a gerund i.e. a noun built from a verb. We can tell this because a gerund can have an article (_the_ helping), a pronoun (_my_ helping), an adjective (the _most effective_ helping), and could have a genitive (the _helping's_ power).

Comment: @BenA. "the most effective helping others is a good habit" is not a grammatical sentence. You can't analyse *helping* on its own.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен Of course, I can. I wanted to demonstrate the capabilities of a gerund. For this, I don't need to take the entire sentence in question.

Comment: But by putting it in the sentence you see it fails all but one of your gerund tests. So in the sentence how can you say it is a gerund?

Comment: @MattE.Эллен I have tried to show all possible capabilities of a gerund. I haven't said that all of them can be applied in the sentence in question. On the other hand, the question is about grammar, not about style. The example you have provided is grammatically _correct_. It's _only_ stilistically a mess.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен 'So in the sentence how can you say it is a gerund?' The causality chain goes like this: What is the subject of the sentences in question? _Helping others_ is the subject. What is a subject? It's a noun or a noun group. So, _helping others_ is a noun group (with the noun _helping_). If _helping_ is a noun it has to be a gerund.

Comment: _Helping_ is not a noun. It's a verb form, and it's got a direct object. That's verb territory. Distinguish between constituents (noun phrases, clauses, etc.) that function as nouns and nouns themselves. Individual nouns are single words. As has been said repeatedly to no apparent effect, _helping others_ is a noun phrase and the subject of _is_. That does not make anything in it a noun.

Comment: @BenA. You're right that occurrence with an article or a modifying  adjective is a property of nouns, not verbs.  However, apparently, you haven't actually looked at the relevant evidence.  Just try adding an article or an adjective to your original example and see what you get.

Comment: @JohnLawler According to Wiktionary a gerund is a verbal form that functions as a verbal noun. Here, two statements are thinkable: 'As a gerund is a verbal form it is a verb.' or 'As a gerund functions as a noun it is a noun.' I am convinced that the second is more suitable because we [produce a noun from another part of speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalization), which is exactly our purpose when we build the -ing form.

Comment: @GregLee Sorry, I don't get your point. I have already added an article, a pronoun, an adjective and have built a genitive in my original post addressed to you. The outcomes are grammatically correct. We are not talking about style here as I mentioned before.

Comment: @JohnLawler By the way, I can't support the inconsequence shown in the examples of [Nominalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalization): Having added -ility, -ness, -y, -ure, -ation, -ment, -al we have _nouns formed from verbs_. But having added -ing we still have a _verb used as a noun_? And the reason is...? Only because the present active participle of a verb - as used in the continuous/progressive tenses - has the same form? Oh, I assume that _helping_ in _helping hands_ is a verb for you (a verb used as an adjective) rather than an adjective, isn't it.

Comment: @JohnLawler We can also argue from etymology. A _gerundium_ is  [which is to be carried out](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gerund). _Which_ doesn't refer to a verb. It refers to a noun - here, to an action. The gerund _helping_ is no less a noun than _help_.

Comment: @BenA. Begin with the entire! example.  Here, I'll do it for you. *"The helping others is a good habit."  *"Open helping others is a good habit."  See?  Both ungrammatical.  On the other hand, "Openly helping others is a good habit."  See?  Grammatical.  If "helping" is really a noun, how come it can't be modified by an adjective, but it can be modified by an adverb?

Comment: @BenA. No, Greg and John are right. They're professionals in this field and know what they're talking about. *Helping* in "helping others" is a verb here, only a verb, and nothing but a verb. **Plus "gerund" is *not* a part of speech!** Lastly, please don't bring Latin into this. It has no place here. See [latin.se] for that.

Answer (score 1):

In the example "Helping others is a good habit", "helping" is a verb and not a noun.  Since "helping others" is the subject of the sentence, it is a noun phrase, and ordinarily the head of a noun phrase is a noun, but not always. Consider the homily "To err is human", where the subject noun phrase "to err" doesn't contain any noun.

So from the fact that "helping others" is a subject, from the fact that it is a noun phrase, we can't conclude that "helping" is a noun. It might be, it probably is, but maybe not.

If we look within the subject noun phrase, "helping" appears to be a verb, not a noun.  It can be modified by an adverb, but not by an adjective: "Openly helping others is a good habit", *"Open helping others is a good habit".  Nouns can be modified by adjectives but not adverbs, so this indicates that "helping" is a verb.

Nouns take preceding articles (to form a noun phrase), but verbs don't.  Applying this as a test, we see that "helping" in the example must not be a noun: *"The helping others is a good habit."

However, "helping" could also be a noun, since there is a suffix "-ing" that forms nouns from verbs.  "Helping" as a noun is a little awkward, but other verbs converted to nouns with this suffix are okay.  However, in the example, "helping" cannot be a noun, because it has a direct object, "others".  Verbs take direct objects but nouns don't. (Logical direct objects after a noun have to be converted to prepositional phrases with "of".)

Comment: Describing "helping" as having properties of both a noun and a verb without identifying it as a gerund is like describing a mule as having both properties of a donkey and a horse without ever calling it a mule.  You miss a larger point.

Comment: @JRodge01 But I didn't do that.  I didn't ascribe any noun properties at all to gerunds.  They're verbs -- just verbs. I'm aware that some say gerunds have some properties of nouns and some of verbs, but not me.  They're verbs.  The phrase category that contains them is a VP, not a NP.

Comment: So you don't identify gerunds as nouns.  This means you disagree with the definition of gerund provided by Merriam Webster, Oxford, and Wikitionary, among others.  Can you provide any sources that support your viewpoint?

Comment: @JRodge01 Evidence matters.  Definitions don't.  Linguistics is not about terminology.  I gave my evidence.

Answer (score -1):

"Helping" is a noun.  It is considered a gerund, which is when an "-ing" verb is treated as a noun.

"Others" is a pronoun.  It is referring to another unspecified group.

Comment: _Helping others_ is a noun, or rather a noun phrase. _Helping_ by itself is a gerund, which is a verb, if you're not playing with the full deck. The OP appears to be trying to do grammar by parsing individual words. Works great for Latin, but doesn't work for English because we don't have much to parse except constructions like phrases and clauses, and lots more parts of speech have been discovered in the last century. Modern science marches on.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  Please read the above comments on the question to see why.  There have been many discussions of gerunds previously on English SE.  This is a very tricky part of English grammar, and many, many people get it wrong.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105260/discussion-on-answer-by-jrodge01-helping-others-is-a-good-habit-which-part-of-s).